# Increment version number in GitHub Actions

Tags: flutter, sed, grep, github-actions

Not an expert on traditional Linux commands as well as grep.
I have a pipeline setup that everytime I make a major release of my application, I want

- Create a GitHub tag
- Increment the version + build in my `pubspec.yaml`

Creating the GitHub tag already works and I used the following command (I assume there is room for improvement too):

```
echo "TAG_NAME=$(cat ${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/pubspec.yaml | grep 'version:' | head -1 | cut -f2- -d: | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//')" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

For the second step however, I am pretty lost. I already considered search/replace the corresponding line in my `pubspec.yaml`, but I don't know how I could now apply such transformation on my version number.

For example:

- 1.2.3+22 -> 1.2.4+23
- 2.14.9+99 -> 2.14.10+100

Edit: The commands I have now working for me are:

```
- name: "Retrieve version"
        id: version
        run: |
          echo "OLD_VERSION=$(cat ${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/pubspec.yaml | grep 'version:' | head -1 | cut -f2- -d: | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//')" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          echo "NEW_VERSION=$(awk '{ match($0,/([0-9]+)\+([0-9]+)/,a); a[1]=a[1]+1; a[2]=a[2]+1; sub(/[0-9]+\+[0-9]+/,a[1]"+"a[2])}1' ${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/pubspec.yaml | grep 'version:' | head -1 | cut -f2- -d: | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//')" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      - name: "Increment version"
        run: |
          sed -i 's/${{ steps.version.outputs.OLD_VERSION }}/${{ steps.version.outputs.NEW_VERSION }}/g' ${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/pubspec.yaml
          echo ${{ steps.version.outputs.OLD_VERSION }}
          echo ${{ steps.version.outputs.NEW_VERSION }}
```

Can probably be optimized a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `awk` is an option, you can try;

```
$ awk '{ match($0,/([0-9]+)\+([0-9]+)/,a); a[1]=a[1]+1; a[2]=a[2]+1; sub(/[0-9]+\+[0-9]+/,a[1]"+"a[2])}1' input_file
1.2.4+23
2.14.10+100
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked for me. Even tho my lines seem overcomplicated now. But at least its working - thanks.